# Determine Character Encoding used on HP 9000 Model 310 running BASIC 5.1

Tags: basic, hp, unicode

With the help of this community, I was able to copy and emulate a HP9133 HD using Hpdir and Hpdrive.

Now, I want to edit, or at the bare minimum, read the programs on the HD. I have extracted the programs using Hpdir, but I am at a loss as to how to determine the encoding used. I can see some text (seems to mainly be variable names, see attached example), but try as I may to find the proper encoding, nothing comes out correctly.

Some things worth noting:

- I have used a number of editors, jEdit seems to have the most encodings available. When I open the programs in jEdit, It defaults to cp-1252 (also known as windows-1252). This is the encoding used in the shown example.
- I have tried a ton of encodings using brute-force from the supported list in jEdit, none seem to work.
- HP 9000 Model 310 running BASIC 5.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
[image: Program viewed in jEdit]

Comment: It's probably not in any character encoding, but in some binary format. Many BASIC interpreters tokenized the source code, replacing keywords with single byte.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly encoded, and quite probably there's some sort of linked list of line numbers interspersed. I assume that if you wanted to transfer further files you'd need to move the hard disk back and forth, which would be burdensome? Otherwise I'd suggest a differential analysis: save `10 LOAD "string"`, then `10 SAVE "string"` and check the difference. If it's one byte then that's a good sign. Try adding a character to `string` and see whether any numbers increase. Change `10` to `20`. Try `PRINT`. Try `PRINT` with a number instead of a string. With a variable, etc, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HP BASIC doesn't normally save programs in ASCII or any other character encoding. Instead it normally stores the program on disk using an internal representation (probably tokenized like other BASIC implementations). Any file in PROG format isn't in a format you can view in an editor.

However HP BASIC does allow the saving a programs in ASCII format.  From [Using the BASIC 5.0/5.1 System](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/9000_basic/5.0/98613-90000_Using_the_BASIC_5.0_5.1_System_Nov87.pdf):

> ### A Closer Look at Storing Programs
>
> To write a program to a mass storage device, you will use either the SAVE or the STORE
>   statement. There is no "right" or "wrong" choice; your choice depends upon the
>   kind of file you want.
>
> - STORE records an internal representation of the program in a PROG file. The
>     main advantage of a PROG file is a rapid retrieval rate .
> - SAVE records the actual text of the program in an ASCII file. The main advantage
>     of an ASCII file is that it can be read as data by a BASIC program or by
>     LIF-compatible devices (such as other HP computers and terminals).

So if you run the commands  `LOAD "AUTOST"` followed by `SAVE "AUTOST_A"` on your HP computer you should have a file you can read on your PC, probably called `AUTOST_A.ASCII`.

Comment: You are a  saint @Ross Ridge! It worked perfectly. Do you happen to know how to handle BDAT files?

Comment: @AMiller Sorry, no. HPDir should be able to show you the record size in the directory listing. Beyond that how the data is stored in the file is going to depend largely on how the program choose to store data in the file. Any integer data is probably going to be stored in big-endian order as that's the byte order 68000 CPUs used.